# min/max function work-around in SAS

Tags: sas

Essentially, what I would like to do is use the min/max function while altering a table. I am altering a table, adding a column, and then having that column set to a combination of a min/max function. In SAS, however, you can't use summary functions. Is there a way to go around this?

There are many more inputs but for the sake of clarity, a condensed version is below! Thanks!

```
%let variable  = 42


    alter table X add Z float; 
        update X
            set C = min(max(0,500 - %sysevalf(variable)),0);
```

Comment: Are you trying to make this `min(max(0,500-42),0)` or `min(max(0,500-variable),0)`?  You have the second, but I wonder if you want the first.

Comment: I want the first. There are many variables that are set to specific numbers that are inputted at the beginning of the program and I'm calling in the values themselves. So, the expression would evaluate to 0.

Comment: Are you trying to use the SQL aggregate functions `min()` and `max()` or the SAS functions `min(,)` and `max(,)`?  The program is using the later since there is more than one argument and the text mentions "summary" functions.

Comment: To be honest I don't what the difference between the SQL/SAS functions are, but if I am understanding what you are saying, I'd like to use the SQL function

Comment: The aggregate functions `MAX()` will find the maximum values over multiple observations. For example MAX(AGE) would find the age of the oldest person. The regular `MAX(,)` function just finds the maximum over its arguments.  For example max(1,2,3,4) would return 4 as the result.

Comment: You need to post example input and output data to make your question clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's remove the `%sysevalf()`, they are not needed and format for readability

```
alter table claims.simulation add Paid_Claims_NoISL float;
update claims.simulation
  set Paid_Claims_NoISL
    = min(
          max(0
              , Allowed_Claims -&OOPM
              , min(Allowed_Claims
                    ,&Min_Paid+ max(Allowed_Claims - &Deductible * &COINS 
                                    ,0
                                )
                )
              , &Ind_Cap_Claim
          )
       );
```

Notice that the first `min()` only has 1 argument.  That is causing your ERROR.  SAS thinks that because it only has 1 input, you want to summarize a column, which is not allowed in an update.

Just take that out and it should work:

```
alter table claims.simulation add Paid_Claims_NoISL float;
update claims.simulation
  set Paid_Claims_NoISL
    = max(0
          , Allowed_Claims -&OOPM
          , min(Allowed_Claims
                ,&Min_Paid+ max(Allowed_Claims - &Deductible * &COINS 
                                ,0
                            )
            )
          , &Ind_Cap_Claim
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

To reference the value of a macro variable you need to use &.

```
%let mvar = 42;
proc sql;
 update X set C = min(max(0,500 - &mvar),0);
quit;
```

Note there is no need to use the macro function `%SYSEVALF()` since SAS can more easily handle the case when the value `&mvar` is an expression than the macro processor can.

```
%let mvar = 500 - 42;
proc sql;
 update X set C = min(max(0,&mvar),0);
quit;
```

Comment: oh yeah. i'm so sorry I forgot to include that. I have the "&" before each variable that I'm calling

Comment: I keep getting the error: ERROR: The value expression referenced by column Paid_Claims_NoISL can not directly contain a summary function.

Comment: In the more complicated code you posted below the MIN() function only has one argument. So SAS thinks you want to aggregate across observations, which you cannot do in this simple update statement.  Do you really want to take the minimum over many observations? Or do you just want to use the min() function to put a ceiling on the value ?

Comment: I simply had one misplaced parentheses...thank you so much! you were very helpful!